# Issue running mocha tests in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm getting the following error while running "npm run test":

[image]

And my package.json is as follows:

```
{
 "name": "express-app",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www",
   "test": "nyc --reporter=lcov mocha ./tests/unitTests --color",
   "integrationTest": "mocha ./tests/integrationTests --exit"
},
 "dependencies": {
  "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "debug": "2.6.9",
  "ejs": "2.5.9",
  "express": "4.16.3",
  "express-mung": "0.5.1",
  "express-validation": "^3.0.2",
  "http-errors": "1.6.3",
  "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
  "prom-client": "11.3.0",
  "swagger-ui-express": "4.0.4"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
   "chai": "4.2.0",
   "chai-http": "4.3.0",
   "mocha": "6.1.4",
   "nyc": "14.1.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried installing mocha globally using the command:

```
npm i -g mocha
```

Even after which I'm getting the above same error. Can anyone please let me know what Im doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
My machine is behind a corporate proxy

Comment: Delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json. Then try again with npm install and npm test. Don't install mocha globally, that will only mess with different versions as you work on other projects.

Comment: @user835611 did whatever you have suggested, uninstalled global mocha by executing "npm uninstall -g mocha" and "npm uninstall mocha" but still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Or other modules installed in the folder for which you're getting the error? Are the dev dependencies being installed?

Comment: No, other modules are not getting any error

Comment: @user835611 can you please tell me how I can confirm if my dev dependencies are being installed?

Comment: Check what files got downloaded inside the node_modules folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212859/discussion-between-tony-mathew-and-user835611).

Comment: @user835611 I have checked node_modules folder, all files are there I believe. I have noticed one thing though, the same code, with same package.json worked just fine in another system. Do you have any idea if its any of the configuration I have done incorrectly in my system?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem with `nyc` itself. Try updating to the version suggested in this github issue: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1205.